# Showing Live webcam on website

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Can we show live webcam on website using Silverlight? 1 Year back i used Flash and Red 5 Media Server to do the same. RED 5 is open source alternative to Flash Media Server. What can be out Media Server in this case? Can i use the same RED5 media server with Silverlight C# too? Or media servers are technology specific. If so, which would be our Media Server in our case? I know Silverlight has webcam support and it can show our webcam. But what about broadcasting?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SocketCoder put together a series of example articles on how to do this on his website [here](http://socketcoder.com/ArticleFile.aspx?index=2&ArticleID=68).  As I recall, he recommends using the CSpeex voice codec along with a simplified Motion-JPEG style video codec.  Having pursued that path at some length, I suspect you'll find that it works in some though not all scenarios.  The CSpeex codec is great, but the Motion JPEG video encoding/decoding is pretty CPU and bandwidth intensive, since it relies on FJCore, a fairly inefficient C# port of a fairly inefficient Java JPEG implementation.  I also understand that a company called [StreamCoders](http://www.streamcoders.com/products/silversuite.html) has a Silverlight H.263 video encoder that supports a nice range of standards, but I haven't tried it yet and I don't know what, if any, limitations it has.  And it's not cheap, starting at 1500 euros for one developer license.